# JsonSerializer throws exception in Blazor Web App .NET 8, when AOT is enabled

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-8.0

I am getting this exception in my Blazor Web App, whenever i try to use JsonSerializer while AOT is enabled. I get the exception when running in debug mode, which i find strange

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Reflection-based serialization has
> been disabled for this application. Either use the source generator
> APIs or explicitly configure the
> 'JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver' property.'

**Steps to reproduce my problem:**

Create a Blazor Web App (WebAssembly) with .NET 8. Got to project properties and enable AOT

[image]

Goto Home.razor and add this code, so we trigger the use of System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer

```
@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var test = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Now run the project in debug mode. When it tries to serialize, i get this exception

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-8/ and related documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.
When I used the Blazor Web App Wasm template, it created two projects for me. A normal project, and a .Client project.
**Do not enable AOT for the normal project**. **Enable AOT for the .Client project**

[image]

Go to project properties for the .Client project, and enable AOT

[image]

When I publish my project now, everything works. My published code is 2.5x faster, than a non-AOT publish.

Like H H said, according to Microsoft documentation, native AOT is not supported for Blazor. Maybe there is a difference between "AOT" and "native AOT"?

Comment: Yes, I think that "native" is the key word here.

Comment: I ran into this exact same issue with by Blazor WASM project (hosted by a Blazor app to serve it) and had enabled AOT in both.  Removing AOT on server side fixed the issue.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

*Native* AoT is not supported for Blazor.

from [the announcement blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-asp-net-core-in-dotnet-8/):

> The following table summarizes ASP.NET Core feature compatibility with native AOT:
> Blazor            ❌Not supported

I kind of get that for Blazor Wasm but apparently it's not supported for Blazor Server-side either.

Comment: Strange. Blazor Wasm had AOT support in .NET 7, which gave a significant performance boost. I guess Blazor Wasm is just slow in .NET 8 then, because of the lack of AOT support

Comment: No, we have a "jiterpreter" and maybe the old wasm AoT toolchain still works. From the same page "...and JSON deserialization is twice as fast!"  But the new(ish) _native AoT_ in aspnet 8 is for server side code (APIs).